# No difference in the distribution of data across classes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, predictive-models, natural-language

I'm having a problem in my Deep Learning model where I encounter a class imbalance and there's no virtual difference between the data for the two classes or they have an identical if not similar distribution.

One way I tried to solve the class imbalance is through resampling to create an evenly distributed training set. However, my model only predicts one class. This is an NLP problem and I am not sure of using techniques like XGBoost to NLP / Deep Learning problems.

I've read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120109183458/https://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/he/PDFfiles/ImbalancedLearning.pdf) paper that recommends SMOTE and from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147021/random-forests-overfitting-unbalanced-classes), am interested in Random Forest, but am not sure of its applicability to NLP. From [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1186/s40537-019-0192-5#Sec14), there are some algorithms I could use and a different loss function I could provide to the algorithm, but I am using a pre-trained model and so am constrained.

My main problem however, is that there may not be an observable difference between the data in the two classes. In general, can ML / DL work if there is no identifiable difference between the data across the two classes?

Is there any way I can try and manually find some difference between the data for the two classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No machine learning method can (reliably) separate classes that are inseparable. Let’s consider two example.

In this first case, we have data generated by $N(0,1)$ with label $0$ and data generated by $N(2,1)$ with label $1$. You might be out of luck when it comes to predicting the label for an observed value of $1$ (equally likely to have come from either distribution), but for something like $4$ or $-2$, you have a pretty good chance of classifying those correctly.

Now consider data generated from $N(0,1)$ with label $0$ and more data generated from $N(0,1)$ with label $1$. Given an observation, do you have any chance of identifying the correct label?

It turns out that you don’t have different classes. Separation is impossible.